# Open new tab in between already open tab in chorme

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I want to open a tab in chrome I use ctrl +t which open my tab at the last of already opened tab. But I want to open my new tab in between of some specific Tab, How can I do this using keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Look for the extensions!

Not quite what you're after but this may help!: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-position-configure/hfchebpfpmpdnninebmopbelkfhofgnd/details

If all fails and if you are a programmer use the Google chrome TAB api (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) to develop a extension.